# Create chart using data from view

Tags: 2010, list-view, chart-web-part

I am able to create chart by connecting chart webpart to list data. But for some data points I want count of data items appearing in list. For this purpose I created a view and used the "Group By" and "Totals" options. But I cannot find any options via which I can connect data from view to chart webpart.

Is there any way I can create chart using information displayed in view?